# Accessing Firebase data from cell in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a picture, three UILabels, and a TextView in a cell and would like to use that data in a separate view controller. The view controller is currently connected via a push segue to the cell, what should I do make this happen?

I have this but it doesn't work:

```
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            self.userLabel.text = dictionary["username"] as? String
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to find a way to do this. It's quite simple actually

prepareForSegue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
        if let indexPath = self.postsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let post = posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
            let postDetails = post["postID"] as? String
            let controller = segue.destination as! PostDetailsViewController
            controller.postDetails = postDetails
        }
    }
}
```

PostDetailsViewController

```
var postDetails: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(postDetails!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            self.idLabel.text = dictionary["postID"] as? String
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a stored variable of type Dictionary to both the source and destination VC's: var userdata:Dictionary! or you can initialize an empty dictionary let userdata = String:Any

Then after you convert the snapshot to a dictionary set the source VC user data to the dictionary data and perform the segue

```
if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
    self.userLabel.text = dictionary["username"] as? String
    self.userdata = dictionary
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "<segueIDHere>", sender: self)
}
```

And then implement the VC prepare for segue method in the source VC to pass the data:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "<segueIDHere>" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! <ClassNameofVCHere>
        destinationVC.userdata = self.userdata 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Which of these should I add to the DetailsViewController (Separate View Controller) and the MainViewController?