# Copy Firebase data from UITableView cell to seperate view controller

Tags: xcode, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app similar to a social media app like Instagram. In the cell, I have a UIImageView and a button which leads to a separate view controller. What I need in the separate view controller is the text loaded from the database in a UILabel which would change depending on which cell was tapped. What would be the best and easiest way to go about this?

More info from one of my comments:
In Firebase, I have a subsection named 'posts' which hold all my posts. Those posts are displayed on the main page in cells that also has a 'Details' button which has a segue to the seperate view controller. What I want to do is call a certain post in the seperate view controller and then display data from that post in a UI Label. Image: [m.imgur.com/c7fEKks?r.png](https://m.imgur.com/c7fEKks?r.png)

Comment: Pretty vague question but there are two immediate solutions. 1) when you populate your initial datasource (array) include the needed data and when segueing to another view controller pass the 'extra' data via the segue. 2) When transitioning to another view controller load the data from Firebase and present in the controller. There are about 50 other ways to solve this as well but without specific use case data, Firebase structure and code, it's just guesswork.

Comment: @jay In Firebase, I have a subsection named 'posts' which hold all my posts. Those posts are displayed on the main page in cells that also has a 'Details' button which has a segue to the seperate view controller. What I want to do is call a certain post in the seperate view controller and then display data from that post in a UI Label. Image: http://m.imgur.com/c7fEKks?r.png

Comment: Understood. Both of the suggestions in my comment would be a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but how would you implement this into my segue code-wise

Comment: Question is really to vague but I added an answer - hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of tutorials available on how to pass data via a segue so this is a quick and short snippet.

Assume the following

A MasterViewController with a tableView that displays user names.
   The tableView has an array dataSource populated with UserClass objects. These objects are populated from Firebase.

```
UserClass {
   userName = ""
   shoeSize = ""
}
```

A DetailViewController with a text label.

A Segue called 'showDetail' of kind Show Detail that's tied to the rows on the tableView on the MasterViewController to the DetailViewController

This segue 'activates' when a row in the tableView is tapped and will display the user's shoe size on the detailViewController

Here's the code (in the MasterViewController) that's called when a row in the masterViewController tableView is tapped.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {           
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
      let aUser = usersArray[indexPath.row]
      let shoeSize = aUser.shoeSize
      let controller = (segue.destination as! 
               UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
      controller.shoeSize = shoeSize
     }
  }
}
```

in the detailViewController when the variable is populated, display it

```
@IBOutlet weak var shoeSizeLabel: UILabel!

func configureView() {
    if let shoe = self.shoeSize {
        if let label = self.shoeSizeLabel {
            label.text = shoe
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.configureView()
}

var shoeSize: String? {
    didSet {
        self.configureView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `(segue.destination as!
                    UINavigationController).topViewController as!DetailViewController)` gives me an expected expression error, where should the parentheses go?

Comment: @gabe Take out the paren after as! DetailViewController. Also, if you want to see the flow, create a brand new project in XCode, and select Master Detail as the type and the segues etc will be in the project template that's created.

Comment: Okay, when viewing the DetailViewConroller all I see is the UILabel, not the FireBase Data. My DetailViewController: http://pastebin.com/8g69sBW5 , MainViewController: http://pastebin.com/jtpkBiWX

Comment: @gabe I left out a couple of things in my answer thinking you would use the master-detail template in XCode - my apologies. See my updated answer with the complete and tested functions.

Comment: Thanks so much. Now I am receiving the error 'Value of type 'DetailsViewController' has no member 'detailItem''

Comment: @gabe Right. Because there is no detailItem variable - it was removed as it wasn't needed - see the code in the answer. The variable is called shoeSize so update your mastercontroller code accordingly

Comment: Oh I see now. I changed it to 'shoeSize' but after the data in the cell loads clicking the 'Detail' button still gives the the default text- not the data from the cell.

Comment: @gabe Well...  I literally copied and pasted code from a working project into the answer so I don't really have any other suggestions.

Comment: Here (http://pastebin.com/YDaWDRZU) is a pastebin of what I put into my ViewControllers. I really appreciate you helping me out on this.

Comment: Your configureView function is not correct and does not match the one in my answer. I am using shoeSize, you are using price.

Comment: It shouldn't matter though as all I changed was the shoeSize to an actual object in my database (price)?

Comment: @gabe You are going to have to do some legwork on your own. You don't have a variable self.price in your destinationViewController so it will never populate :-/

Comment: I'm sorry, as you can probably tell I'm new with Swift and Firebase- most of my time I spend googling trying to figure out how to do stuff.

Comment: @gabe Remember to accept the answer if it helped! Which it seems to have! :-)

Comment: I was finally able to solve this thanks to your help. (Link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42403978/7548760) Thanks again!